# c++ operator new how this works internally

Tags: c++, new-operator

For example I have a simple code:

```
class B
{
};

class A
{
    B b;
    public:
    A()
    {
        throw 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = 0;
    try
    {
        a = new A;
    }
    catch (int)
    {
    }
}
```

Constructor A throws exception, then destructor will not be called. But destructor for B will be called. Memory in the heap will not be allocated. My question how this works internally? What will be first: constructing A or allocating memory in the heap? So, if allocating is the first, how deallocating will be handled if there are exception? Othervise, if constructing A is the first, how it's copiing to the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The memory is allocated.
2. The constructor of A is called.
3. The constructor of A calls the constructor of B.
4. The constructor of A throws.
5. As a part of the standard exception handling procedure, the destructor of B is called (RAII at work).
6. The stack unwinds to the caller (main).
7. The memory is deallocated (because the object wasn't constructed successfully).

The destructor of A isn't called because the object was not fully constructed. However, the members which *were* fully constructed are still destroyed.

The memory is deallocated automatically in pretty much the same way as local variables are destroyed when the control leaves the block. If you're familiar with Java and/or C#, think of it as an invisible `try-finally` construct. Or a series of such constructs.

Comment: Thanks, your comment is nice, but I need more information. What is the mechanism to provide destructors behavior in the heap memory like stack?

Comment: @M90, I think the mechanism is implementation-specific. Like I said, an invisible `try-finally` block. Like, if something goes wrong, the control transferred to some auto-generated code that takes care of whatever needs taken care of, and then continues on with the propagating exception. Compile your code into assembly to see how it *really* works, if you're that curious.

Comment: @M90 See also Herb Sutter's [Constructor Failures...](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm)

Comment: @SergeyTachenov you don't go into explaining what happens if some of the data members are `new`-ed in the constructor's body before the exception happens; that is: pretty much the same as it happens in any block of code that throws. So either RAII or ... handle your deallocation before in a catch-(re)throw.

Comment: @Adrian, but that's outside the scope of the question. There's zillion of things to be aware of when writing exception safe code especially when it comes to constructors and destructors, and it can't possibly be covered in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What will be first: constructing `A` or allocating memory in the heap?

Unless there's memory, there's no space in which the object can be constructed. Memory allocation always goes first; then the code proceeds with initialization. This applies to all kinds of memory allocations, not only of the dynamic variety, because constructors need to have a valid address of `this` before they start initializing the object.

> If allocating is the first, how deallocating will be handled if there are exception?

The compiler emits special code that handles the "magic" here. This code will run destructors for all base classes, and for members, such as `B`, that have been fully constructed by the time the code entered `A`'s constructor.

Comment: Thanks, could you please describe in details this "special code" behavior?

Comment: @M90 I already did: run destructors for everything that has been fully constructed, and then return the allocated memory to where it came from (in your case, it came from the heap, so back to the heap it goes).